# Encode printing of alphabets in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops

In this program i have encoded 
Using the numerical value of each letter (A=1, B=2, ... Z= 26) the rules are as follows:
A–E     Multiply its numerical value by 2 
F–J     Divide its numerical value by 3. Multiply the integer remainder by 5 
K–O     Divide its numerical value by 4. Multiply the integer remainder by 8.
P–T     Add 10.
U- Z    Find the largest integer factor of its numerical value less than the            value itself. Multiply it by 12.

As an example if the letter to encode is a B, the B has a numerical value of 2 and encodes to a  4 and becomes a D, the 4th letter of the alphabet.

The G has a numerical value of 7. It encodes to a 5 and becomes an E.

The numerical value of Z is 26. Its largest factor is 13. You must count 156 (13*12) letters. This has the effect of wrapping around the alphabet 6 complete times and ending at Z. If a numerical value of zero is evaluated print a # symbol. 
  Problem with the code
 - I am not able to print #.
 - whenever i am entering Y i am getting J why???????

Here is my code:

```
  #include<stdio.h>

  void main()
  {
  char c;
  int n,i,max=0,j,y;
    int a[]={65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90};
    scanf("%c",&c);
    n=c;
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
          int flag=0;
            if(a[i]==n )
            {
                 flag=1;
            }
        if(flag==1)
            {
                 printf("%c",a[((i+1)*2)-1]);
                 break;
            }
        }




    for(i=5;i<10;i++)
      {
        int flag=0;
        if(a[i]==n )
            {
                 flag=1;
            }
        if(flag==1)
            {
                 printf("%c",a[(((i+1)%3)*5)-1]);
                 break;
            }
      }



    for(i=10;i<15;i++)
        {
          int flag=0;
          if(a[i]==n )
            {
                 flag=1;
            }
        if(flag==1)
            {
                 printf("%c",a[(((i+1)%4)*8)-1]);
                 break;
            }
        }




        for(i=15;i<20;i++)
          {
             int flag=0;
             if(a[i]==n )
            {
                 flag=1;
            }
        if(flag==1)
            {
                 printf("%c",a[((i+1)+10)-1]);
                 break;
            }
        }





     for(i=15;i<26;i++)
    {
        int flag=0;
        if(a[i]==n )
            {
                    flag=1;
                    for(j=1;j<=(i+1)/2;j++)
                          {
                                if((i+1)%j==0)
                                     {
                                        if(max<j)
                                             {
                                                max=j;
                                             }
                                     }
                          }
              }

          if(flag==1)
             {

                 y=(max*12)/6;
                 if(y>=0)
                     {
                        printf("%c",a[y-1]);
                     }
                  else
                     {
                         printf("#");
                     }
                  break;
             }


     }


 }
```

Help me out guy's.

Comment: Has anybody ever warned you about magic numbers? You can do better than this: `int a[]={65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90};`...

Comment: An input of 'A' results in an output of 'B'. What do you expect 'Y' to encode to?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour suggest me the better one,i am in learning phase.Your help can do a lot to me.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain why `Y` should map to `#`. The largest factor of 25 is 5.  5 * 12 = 60. 60 - 52 = 8. So doesn't `Y` map to `H`?

Comment: @DeepakKumar - as user3386109 asks, would you explain the process by which an input of `Y` should result in an output of  `#`. Also, consider declaring the array thusly: `int a[] = {'A', 'B', etc, etc`

Comment: @user3386109 you are correct I made the mistake.I calculated wrongly.

Comment: @user3386109 could you please tell me if the first condition in first loop is executed than how can i ignore other loops and condition.

Comment: Instead of `break`, you can use `exit(0)`. That will cause the program to terminate at that point. The `exit` function is declared in `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @DeepakKumar I imagine I don't need to tell you about `unsigned char a[26] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";`

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour instead of using unsigned char i have used another logic of extracting the position and do required calculations on them.See my updated code.

Comment: @user3386109 in your one of the above comments you have used 60-52 why you have used 52 to subtract it from 60?Please explain me this.

Comment: The numerical value of `Y` is 25. Its largest factor is 5. You must count 60 (5*12) letters. This has the effect of wrapping around the alphabet 2 times (52 letters), and ending at `H`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int large(int n);
  int main()
  {
  char c;
  int n,y;




    scanf("%c",&c);
    n=c;



  if(n>=65 && n<70)
        {

        int val;
        val=(((n-65)+1)*2)+64;
        printf("%c\n",val);

        }




  else if(n>=70 && n<75)
      {

         int val=(n-65+1);
         if((val)%3!=0)
         {
         printf("%c\n",(((val)%3)*5)+64);

         }
         else printf("#\n");

      }




    else if(n>=75 && n<80)
        {

            int val=(n-65+1);
            if((val)%4!=0)
         {
            printf("%c\n",(((val)%4)*8)+64);

          }
            else
            printf("#\n");


        }


        else if(n>=80 && n<85)
          {
                 int val=n-65+1;

                 if(val>16)
                    {
                     val=val-26;
                    printf("%c",val+10+64);

                    }
                    else
                 printf("%c\n",(val+10)+64);

          }





      if(n>=85 && n<91)
    {
        int d,b=0,m;
        int val=n-65+1;
                 d=large(val);
                 y=(d*12);
                  while(b<y)
                  {
                     b=b+26;
                    }
                    b=b-26;
                  m=y-b;

                 printf("%c\n",m+64);

             }



            return 0;
 }


 int large(int n)
    {
      int j,max=0;
        for(j=1;j<=n/2;j++)
         {
            if(n%j==0)
              {
                 if(max<j)
                     {
                        max=j;
                     }
              }
        }
        return max;
        }
```

Comment: @enhzflep,@user3386109 now give a look to this code working fine,and still if there is any problem in this,please do tell me.

Answer (score 1):

You have a variety of rules for encoding the characters, but at the end of the day, each letter of the alphabet maps to a single output character. So you can simply create a table that contains the outputs that correspond to each letter. Thus the code reduces to the following

```
int main( void )
{
    char table[] = "BDFHJ#EJ#EX#HPXZABCDFBLJHZ";
    char c;
    if ( scanf("%c",&c) == 1 && c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' )
        printf( "%c\n", table[c - 'A'] );
}
```

Note that the table in this code attempts to follow the rules that you specified. Those rules don’t create a 1-to-1 mapping of input to output, but of course it’s trivial to change the table to achieve any mapping you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int maxFac(int n)
{
    int i,max=0;
    for(i=2;i<=n/2;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            if(max<i)
            max=i;
        }
    }

    return max;
}

int main()
{
char c;
scanf("%c",&c); 

if((int)c>=65 && (int)c<=69)
  {
    c=(((int)c-64)*2)+64;
  }     

 else if ((int)c>=70 && (int)c<=74)
   {
     c= (((int)c-64)%3)*5;
     if(c==0)
       c='#';
     else
       c=(int)c+64;
    }

    else if((int)c>=75 && (int)c<=79)
    {

        c= (((int)c-64)%4)*8;

            if(c==0)

            c='#';

            else

            c=(int)c+64;

    }

    else if((int)c>=80 && (int)c<=84)

    {

        c= c+10;

        if(c>90)

        c=c-26;

    }

    else if((int)c>=85 && (int)c<=90)

    {

        int z;

        c=c-64;

        z=maxFac(c);

        c=z;

        c=(z*12)%26 + 64;

        if(c=='@')

        c=c+26;

    }



    printf("%c",c);

}
```